# Scrape data from PDF with python but not from a table or a normal te

Tags: python, pdf-scraping

Hello guys and thank you in advance for helping me.

So basically, i am trying scrape data from a pdf.

this is the pdf data:

[image]

what i want to do is extract data from it like that:

[image]

i tried to do it with tabula but gave me this:

[image]

and i tried with regular expression but nothing.

can you please help me

```
import tabula
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np


df = (pd.concat(
         tabula.read_pdf(
              "/content/drive/MyDrive/Stage/word.pdf", pages="all", pandas_options={"header": None}))
         .squeeze().str.extract(r"\)\s*([^\s]+)\s*([a-z\s,]+)?\s*([A-Z\s]+)?\s*(\w\d+)")
         .stack(dropna=False).strip().unstack()
         .set_axis(["word", "type", "comment", "suffix"], axis=1)
     [["word", "type"]] #uncomment this line to match your expected output
     )

df.to_excel("table.xlsx", index=False) #uncomment this line to make a spreadsheet
print(df)
```

Comment: @tous, why *preposition* is not a type of the word *aboard* in your expected ouptut ?

Answer (score 3):

You can try something like this with [tabula-py](/questions/tagged/tabula-py) & [pandas](/questions/tagged/pandas) :

```
import tabula
​
df = (pd.concat(
         tabula.read_pdf(
              "file.pdf", pages="all", pandas_options={"header": None}))
         .squeeze().str.extract(r"\)\s*([^\s]+)\s*([a-z\s,]+)?\s*([A-Z\s]+)?\s*(\w\d+)")
         .stack(dropna=False).str.strip().unstack()
         .set_axis(["word", "type", "comment", "suffix"], axis=1)
     #[["word", "type"]] #uncomment this line to match your expected output
     )

#df.to_excel("table.xlsx", index=False) #uncomment this line to make a spreadsheet
```

Output :
​

```
print(df)

           word                 type       comment suffix
0       abandon                 verb    STOP DOING     C1
1      abnormal            adjective           NaN     C1
2        aboard  adverb, preposition           NaN     C1
3      abortion                 noun           NaN     C1
4   absolutely!                  NaN           NaN     C1
5        absorb                 verb      REMEMBER     C1
6         abuse                 noun  WRONG ACTION     C1
7    accelerate                 verb        HAPPEN     C1
8    acceptable            adjective       ALLOWED     C1
9    acceptance                 noun           NaN     C1
10     accepted            adjective           NaN     C1
```

*PDF used :*

[image]

Comment: it gave me that error AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'str'

Comment: WIth a pdf that matches your example, the code actually works. Either, you failed to describe your dataset or your doing something wrong. Either way, can you make a reproducible example that triggers the error ? Also, can you include your code in the question ?

Comment: I'm a bit confused, how you came up with the OP's pdf ?

Comment: Cool, AWK now, I'll see if I can find it as well and then re-adapt my answer later. Thanks K J ;)

Comment: it didnt work even with the file that Mr K J told me about :(